# json.load(json_ob) results in error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I've created a json object by calling an API:

```
import urllib.request  as urllib2 
import json
api_key = '...api_key_here...'
request_url = 'http://api....url_here....xml?attribute=XXXX&api_key=blah'

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(request_url)
```

That runs without error.

Then I tried to run:

```
data = json.load(json_obj)
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: I would recommend printing out what comes back in `json_obj`. That error is saying the very first character is unexpected for JSON. I see that "xml" is mentioned in your request URL, so are you sure the response is JSON?

Comment: Ahh! Good catch! Thanks. Its XML o_O

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import requests
import json

api_key = '...api_key_here...'
request_url = 'http://api....url_here....xml?attribute=XXXX&api_key=blah'

json_obj = json.loads(requests.get("request_url").text)
```